# SharePoint filter on year

Tags: date, sharepoint, filter, infopath

currently i have a date in SharePoint, but I want to filter on Year.

What I have is that I can filter on all documents from 25-11-2014. But I have also documents from 20-11-2014. I want to filter only on year, somebody know how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column named **Year** with this formula inside

```
=YEAR([ColumnName])
```

Set decimal place setting to 0 and filter for this column

See this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection2) for more details on calculated column

Comment: Thxx it works, but it shows like 2.014. I have the decimal on 0.

Comment: I know, you can use XSLT or javascript